# Объявление глобальной переменной внутри прекомпилированного заголовка

Tags: c++

Вот пример как следует объявлять переменные и функции.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
int a = 5; 
bool operator<(const int & p, const int & q){return p < q;}
int main()
{
}
```

Содержимое #include "StdAfx.h"

```
[[
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <fstream>

extern int a;// правильно
extern int a = 7;// ошибка
int a = 7;// ошибка

extern bool operator<(const int & p, const int & q); // правильно
bool operator<(const int & p, const int & q){return p < q;} // ошибка
]]
```

Но я хочу в  `StdAfx.h` поместить все свои и сторонние библиотеки.

Однако варианты с `extern` приводят к огромным трудностям, понижению компактности и децентрализации управления.

Неужели необходимо для каждой переменной указывать `extern`, а в дальнейшем создавать с инициализацией еще и после `StdAfx`?

Comment: Вы хотите использовать прекомпилированный заголовок *не по назначению*. Да, он предназначен для ускорения времени компиляции, однако в нем должны содержаться исключительно **редко изменяемые определения**, например, сторонних библиотеки или модулей других компонентов, а также всевозможные константы. Иначе выгоды от него особой не получите.
Код вашего модуля, в том числе глобальные функции и переменные (которых вообще следует избегать), не стоит туда вносить, а лучше выделить в отдельный компактный заголовочный файл, который не будет замедлять сборку.

Comment: Определение функции в хедере - это сразу 10 лет расстрела на месте.

Comment: За static inline тоже?

Comment: Почему? static inline - это нормально.

Answer (score 3):

[[@manking](/users/7538/manking)](/users/7538/manking), откровенно скажу, будет ли это работать в **StdAfx.h**, не знаю.

В случае подобному Вашему, для решения можно воспользоваться директивами препроцессора `#ifdef`

Например заголовочный файл

```
// tt.h
#ifndef TT_H
#define TT_H

extern int XAXA;
#ifdef MAIN_PART 
int XAXA = 7;
#endif

#endif
```

файлы кода

```
// tt.c  здесь реально разместим extern переменные
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "tt.h"

main()
{
  ttt();
  printf("%d\n",XAXA);
}
```

и

```
// ttt.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "tt.h"

ttt ()
{
  printf ("ttt %d\n",XAXA);
}
```

компилируем

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -c ttt.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc tt.c ttt.o -DMAIN_PART
```

и запускаем

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
ttt 7
7
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Но, как такой прием будет работать в предварительно откомпилированных заголовках - не знаю.

**UPD**  по теме static, global и т.п.

Возьмем 2 файла t.c и tt.c

```
// t.c
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

extern int b_int_global;
static int a_int_static = 0x41424344;
static int cont_it_as_str = 0x00444342;

main ()
{
  printf ("t:a_int_static = %d %s\n",a_int_static,(char *)&a_int_static);
  tt();
  (&b_int_global)[1] = 1000;
  tt();
  exit (0);
}

// tt.c
#include <stdio.h>

int b_int_global = 1000;
static int a_int_static = 10;

tt ()
{
  printf ("tt:a_int_static = %d\n",a_int_static);
}
```

Откомпилируем в .o и посмотрим на таблицы имен

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc -c t.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ nm t.o
00000000 d a_int_static
         U b_int_global
00000004 d cont_it_as_str
         U exit
00000000 T main
         U printf
         U tt
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc -c tt.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ nm tt.o
00000004 d a_int_static
00000000 D b_int_global
         U printf
00000000 T tt
```

Сделаем загрузочный модуль и запустим его

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc t.o tt.o
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
t:a_int_static = 1094861636 DCBABCD
tt:a_int_static = 10
tt:a_int_static = 1000
```

Убедимся, что константы в модулях еще до запуска

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ grep DCBABCD a.out
Двоичный файл a.out совпадает
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ grep DCBABCD t.o
Двоичный файл t.o совпадает
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Надеюсь это прояснит ситуацию с static, extern, что где в памяти лежит и подскажет как  надо объявлять переменные.

Comment: Нет это не подходит. 
Собственно смысл всего вопроса - можно ли без геморроя поместить любой файл который нормально компилируется в глобальной области видимости, в прекомпилированный заголовок.

Вот если вы подключаете какую то часть boost. 
Вам она очень нужна. Кладете это в StdAfx.h
И тут лезут ошибки
"обнаружен многократно определенный символ" - потому что у boost есть глобальные переменные.
Изменять boost вы никак не можете. 
Вот в данном случаи как то можно всё таки скомпилировать?

Comment: Не пользоваться StdAfx.h

Comment: В общем суть я понял. Но по вашему комментарию, а не этому ответу. Очень уж он запутан.
Глобальная переменная и статическая глобальная переменная по содержимому равны. Они видны везде, и отличаются лишь временем инициализации. Для простых типов достаточно знать, что инициализация произойдет раньше её использования.

Таким образом самый простой путь использования глобальных переменных внутри прекомпилированного заголовка это, сделать их статическими.
Но в таком случаи придётся изменять содержимое модулей помещенных в stdafx.

Comment: @manking, если глобальные (extern) заменить на static, то они будут видны **только из этого модуля**. Это раз. 

А самое главное - два (не понял, Вы это понимаете или нет) все extern с одним именем - это **одна и та же переменная** для всех модулей (один экземпляр в памяти), а вот все static будут **разными**, каждая в своем модуле.

Если Вы также считаете, просто я не понимаю этого, то хорошо. Только я не представляю, насколько просто переделать все Ваши модули под новую архитектуру.

Зачем Вам вообще эта предкомпиляция? Напишите нормальный Makefile и все будет ОК.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю что из себя представляет понятие модуль.
static виден если модуль:
1) это файл #include ""                      - виден

2) это обобщенное название группы практически автономных классов   - виден

3) это файл .cpp, который компилируется отдельно, но является частью проекта-решения. - не виден. 

Вы как я понимаю говорите про 3 вариант, и показали это на gcc. Я такие многомодульные решения видел в различным библиотеках, но на visual studio. 

Но это не мой вариант. У меня везде предполагается вариант 1.

Answer (score 2):

Предкомпилируемый заголовочный файл StdAfx.h работает следующим образом. После любого изменения в нём (или в тех файлах, которые он в себя включает) компилятор обрабатывает его содержимое и в конце тупо сохраняет состояние своих символьных таблиц во внешний файл в удобном ему бинарном формате. В последующие разы (если StdAfx.h не изменился) он просто быстро загружает из этого файла символьные таблицы, и они оказываются в состоянии, как будто бы компилятор только что честно прошёл по всему содержимому. Именно поэтому StdAfx.h всегда должен включаться в любой файл самой первой строкой.

Нужно понимать, что инициализация - это действие, совершаемое над переменной. Т.е. обработка этой языковой конструкции подразумевает генерацию кода. Пусть и весьма тривиального. Было бы странно, если бы компилятор хранил в своих символьных таблицах не только символы, но и ещё какой-то выполняемый код. Это бы серьёзно всё усложнило, поскольку появилась бы явная взаимосвязь между совершенно разными фазами компиляции - между фазой разбора и фазой генерации кода. Притом что компиляторы - это и так очень сложная вещь. Короче говоря, я не думаю, что кому-нибудь понравился бы такой компилятор, который генерирует код уже в процессе разбора символов. Это бы полностью обессмыслило идею разделения файлов на модульные и заголовочные. Идея, кстати, уже не выглядит удачной в наше время. Но раз уж она лежит в основе языка, то нужно это учитывать.

Comment: Да, но почему статические переменные он позволяет инициализировать?

Comment: @manking Потому что статические переменные инициализируются не там, где объявляются, а за мгновение до первого использования. И значит в процессе прохождения по заголовку компилятор не генерирует никакого кода вне зависимости от того, есть инициализация или нет.

Comment: @Shamov, я не специалист по архитектуре компиляторов, но все же не могу согласиться с вашим ответом.

Например, что есть *символ* функции, как не собственно ее тело, т.е. код. Символ - это именно содержимое, *тело* кода.

Далее, предкомпилированный файл может содержать *любой* допустимый для других заголовочных файлов код, хоть встраиваемые шаблонные функции. Да и потом, разделение транслируемых файлов на заголовочные и файлы реализации - распространенный способ организации исходных текстов в проекте, и как он может выглядеть неудачной, я не понимаю. Прямо к языку это никак не относится!

Comment: @vladimir_ki А имя переменной - это её значение? :)

Comment: Имя переменной - это лишь ее *идентификатор*, используемый на этапе компиляции и компоновки. В исполняемом (бинарном) модуле его не будет существовать: в общем случае, вместо нее будет адрес.

Comment: А нельзя по умолчанию все глобальные переменные считать статическими?
Насколько я понимаю,когда то раньше между ними было различие в области действия, а сейчас они вроде идентичны?

Comment: @vladimir_ki То же самое и с функциями. В исполняемом коде их символы отсутствуют и заменяются на адреса. Если бы символом функции было её тело, то невозможно было бы написать ни одной собственной функции, поскольку их тела всё время удалялись бы из исполняемого кода. Можно было бы использовать лишь готовые библиотечные функции, поставляемые в виде отдельных модулей. И, кстати, вопрос о том, кто и как делает такие отдельные модули, остался бы открытым.

Comment: @manking Нет, нельзя. Как раньше, так и сейчас они отличаются тем, в какой момент происходит инициализация.

Comment: Инициализация меня особо не заботит.
Я просто читал, что статическая глобальная переменная, видна не везде а только для одного .cpp где указана.
Но дальше человеку ответили, мол это устаревший стандарт. Сейчас она видна везде.

Comment: @manking, статическая переменная видна только в том модуле, где она описана. В другом модуле переменная с таким же именем - это уже другая. Глобальная (нестатической она естественно быть не может) одна для всех модулей. Она **должна** определяться только в одном модуле, а остальные на нее ссылаются. Присвоивание **константных значений** всем статическим переменным происходит при *компиляции*.

--

Для иллюстрации я сделаю **UPD** к своему ответу, посмотрите, что непонятно - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

В файле StdAfx.h объявляете переменную. В тех файлах, которым нужно ее использовать - подключаете StdAfx.h. В одном месте, например в main(), инициализируете. Все.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что вот, допустим, программа использует различные вспомогательные инструменты

`#include "work_DB.h"
#include "work_files.h"
#include "work_math.h"
int main()
{
}`


Всё это очень долго компилируется. Я хочу по простому положить все эти файлы включения в #include "StdAfx.h". Должно выйти так:

`#include "StdAfx.h"
int main()
{
}`


Файлы включения содержат глобальные переменные. Трогать файлы "work_", то есть изменять их содержимое не хочется.

Comment: Не вижу никаких проблем. Должно работать.
Пусть себе глобальные переменные сидят в include файлах.

К директиве include нужно относиться просто - она говорит "вставь содержимое файла" Не больше, не меньше. Если в вставляемом файле есть свои include, процедура рекурсивно повторяется.  Поэтому, простенький main.cpp может развернуться препроцессором в тысячи строк.

Суть "прекомпилированных заголовков" в том, что препроцессор собирает эти все хедеры один раз в один файл и потом просто быстро вставляет. И ещё компилятор делает "черновой проход" и потом не парсит эти файлы много раз.

Comment: Но тогда вываливаются ошибки:

error LNK2005: "int r" (?r@@3HA) уже определен в stdafx.obj

fatal error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более

Comment: Естественно, а как линкеру понять к какой из этих (определенных в разных .o модулях) глобальных переменных обращаться?

@manking, а мое предложение с условной трансляцией не проверили?

Comment: глобальная переменная определена в множестве файлов? В main.cpp ее уже не нужно определять. Она уже есть. Переменная должна быть определена строго в одном месте.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы же видите, что @manking **хочет** объявлять все в  "StdAfx.h". О чем и вопрос.

 Переменные - это так, для примера. Насколько я понимаю в основном все упирается в определения вроде

    bool operator<(const int & p, const int & q){return p < q;}