# C++/CLI. Обновить данные в форме

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Добрый вечер, есть вопрос, являющийся продолжением этого [C++/CLI, глобальный экземпляр формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419407/c-cli-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B)
Но сейчас проблема в следующем, подобную операцию (обновление данных в форме) мне нужно совершать из обеих форм (Coachs, Visitors).

Подключить обе формы друг в друге я не могу, он ругается, а именно если в Coachs пишу `#include "Visitors.h"` и в Visitors пишу `#include "Coachs.h"`.

Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы я мог обращаться из обеих форм друг к другу. Либо подключить их как написал выше. Либо я попробовал написать метод в статическом классе, но там почему-то вылезает `ошибка error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "ооп::xCoachs"` Ругается на строке `form3->CoachInfo();`

Вот собственно, как я модифицировал класс из вопроса, ссылка на который указана в начале.

```
namespace ооп
{
    ref class Visitors;
    ref class xCoachs;
    ref class GlobalForm abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        static Visitors^ form2;
        static xCoachs^ form3;
        static void CoachsReview()
        {
            form3->CoachInfo();
        }   
    };
}
```

Надеюсь, что здесь меня снова выручат, извиняюсь за свою тупость. Дело в том, что надо обязательно этот проект сдать на C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартное решение проблемы перекрёстных зависимостей, что в чистом C++, что в C++/CLI: попробуйте вынести имплементацию в .cpp-файл.

```
// .h
namespace ооп
{
    ref class Visitors;
    ref class xCoachs;
    ref class GlobalForm abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        static Visitors^ form2;
        static xCoachs^ form3;
        static void CoachsReview();
    };
}

// .cpp
#include "Visitors.h"
#include "xCoachs.h"
#include "GlobalForm.h"

namespace ооп
{
    void GlobalForm::CoachsReview()
    {
        form3->CoachInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал так, теперь проект запускается, но почему-то глобальные переменные и экземпляры классов, объявленные в .h файле, в котором и этот статический класс стали пустыми в форме Visitors.h. А в форме xCoachs все норм. `static Gym *gym = new Gym(100, 10, 30, 100);
static Pool *pool = new Pool(20, 10);
static Buffet *buffet = new Buffet(1);
...
static int humanID;`

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Ы? Дайте код. (Наверное, это отдельный вопрос.)

Comment: VladD, вот код, https://yadi.sk/d/_3hVIqXHgFz4t Посмотрите, пожалуйста, с инклюдами вроде все норм:(

Comment: VladD, не  могу найти ошибку. Довольно странно, когда убираю новый .cpp файл, все работает, данные видны в форме, когда же подключаю - они теряются:(

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: У вас куча кода наподобие `static char *objectLogger =  "obj.log";` Это ж неправильно. Данные надо лишь описывать в .h, а иициализировать в .cpp. и static вроде бы неправильно. Не знаю, в этом проблема, или ещё где-то.

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: а какая конкретно переменная имеет неправильное значение?

Comment: Векторы coachs и simulator  читаются из файла при загрузке главной формы, и были видны во всех 3 формах, сейчас в форме Visitors векторы пустые

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что здесь дело в инициализации, ведь данные в векторы записываются при загрузке формы MyForm.h, которая загружается первой.

Comment: Тогда может быть это проблема программы? Поставьте breakpoint на загрузку данных из файла и убедитесь, что она происходит до обращения к форме Visitors

Comment: Да, загрузка данных происходит до загрузки формы Visitors.h Во время загрузки первой формы, из которой я открываю Visitors.

Comment: (Посмотрел код) АААААААААА! Что вы делаете? Вы вызываете вручную деструкторы?

Comment: Это прихоть препода. Ей нужно "показать", что мы вызываем деструкторы. Хотя, по идее, они вызывается сами при закрытии приложения.

Comment: Этот баг связан именно с кривым подключением файлов в проекте?

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Пока не знаю. Какое текущее состояние проблемы? Всё ещё не работает?

Comment: да, не работает, вот вижу пытаюсь все еще исправить, пока что ничего не изменилось...

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Поставьте breakpoint'ы в разных точках, посмотрите, когда (1) один и тот же адрес у `simulator` или разные? (2) где в `simulator` появляются данные, и где исчезают?

Comment: При запуске создаются 3 копии всех объектов. Все имеют один и тот же адрес. Когда я ставлю breakpoint событие Load формы Visitors векторы уже пустые. Но если на событие Load другой формы. то все норм:(

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: всех — это каких?

Comment: Объектов, объявленных глобально, конкретно - векторов, подразумеваю, что экземпляров классов Gym, Pool и др тоже создается по 3

Comment: Почему-то создается пустая копия объекта, в форме Visitors все объекты пустые, а как только я перехожу в другую форму, там все данные есть

Comment: Хм. Что означает «перехожу»?

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Но всё же. Вы бы избавились от `static`, и сделали правильно. Проблема вполне может быть в этом.

Comment: Мне нужно передавать векторы в конструкторе формы Visitors?

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Нет, это отдельная история. Просто `static` значит совсем не то, что вы думаете. Смотрите часть 3: http://rsdn.ru/forum/info/FAQ.cpp.static Тогда вы поймёте, почему в разных файлах это и правда могут быть разные экземпляры.

Comment: Просто, если я уберу static, то проект просто не запускается. Если только передавать данные в конструкторе. Или есть другие варианты?

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: `static` для глобальной переменной — вообще не вариант. Оно не означает глобальную переменную и никогда не означало. Задайте отдельно лучше вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub: Например, вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/152643/10105, http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/501187.all